# How record insert time in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I want to remove a table row from my table new_data once the row is 45 mins old and then input it in another table called old_data.

The only way i can think for this to work, it to query the database lets say every min and remove any row thats (current_time - time inserted) > 45 mins.

Is there any other way of doing this? if not how could i set up a table to record inserted_time?

## edit added

How could i write this statement to retrieve the correct data into the old_data table

`SELECT * FROM new_spots WHERE (NOW()-created_at)>45mins`

and then insert the above into the old_data table

Comment: How frequently the insertion happens?

Comment: It for a mobile app, so based on the number of users, it could be from 10 to a 1000 an hour (for the moment). A user inputs new information and its stored for 45 mins in one table and then moved to another.

Comment: inserting into one table and removing from other each time seems costly. Isn't it possible to take a field (isDeleted or isValid) in the table and update it after 45 mins. This will be more easy.

Comment: @Harry Joy ,that seems a better idea but i would still have to query the database every 1-2 mins to remove to change the validity of the old information.

Comment: you can do update at every 2 mins.

Comment: For your query question: it is easy:  insert into old_data
select * from new_data where timestampdiff(SECOND, now(), created_at) > 2700;

Answer (score 1):

you can specify value of time column upon insertion:

```
INSERT INTO x (created_at) VALUES (NOW());
```

additionally you can setup `VIEW` to show you only recent entries.

Answer (score 1):

you are asking for some kind of `auto expiration` feature, it is not built into mysql. [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) provides this feature. So it might be cleaner to achieve your goal as:

when you insert data into your system, you do:

1. insert your data into memcached with 45 minutes expiration time -- after 45 minutes, the data automatically disappear from memcached.
2. insert the data into the old_data table with a `created_at` column -- in case you need to rebuild your memcached when your memcached have to restart or other issue.

So everytime you just need to get the new data from  the memcached -- as a side effect, it is faster than get the data from mysql :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an automatic way to do this. Here are some alternative ideas.

#### Use CRON

I have a similar scenario where we need to aggregate data from one table into another. A simple command line tool running via CRON suffices. We receive a few messages a second into our Web server and each results in a database insert. So volumes aren't huge but they are reasonably similar to your scenario

We use the NOW() function to record the insert time and after the records are 1hr old, we process them. It isn't exactly an hour but it is good enough. You can see the created_on field below.

```
CREATE TABLE glossaries (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,

    # Our stuff ...

    created_on datetime default NULL,
    KEY owner_id (owner_id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

#### Use CRON and a Trigger

Alternatively you could use a **database trigger** to kick off the processing. You would still need something scheduled to cause the trigger to fire but you would get max performance/

Chris

Comment: My information will be quite real_time and once it is 45 mins old, it must be removed from the new_data table ... once an hour is not often enough

Comment: what effects on the system would be seen if i queried the database for this information

Comment: Then run it more frequently - we run every 10mins.

Comment: @molleman - what kind of effects are you talking about? We see a pretty negligible time taken to process the table and we are doing it in Ruby. We receive a few messages a second which result in db updates.

Comment: My thinking was wrong previously, the effects would be minimal which is perfect.

Comment: @molleman - no problem, I think our volumes are similar to yours ~1000 per hour. If you are concerned about performance, why not use the cron/db trigger approach?

Answer (score 0):

@keymone showed you how to capture the insert time.  Then, periodically (every minute seems excessive - every 5 mins?  15 mins?) go through and build a list that meets the criteria, and for each entry, insert into your second table and delete from your first table.

Comment: How would i be able to query the database for the information that i need. i was thinking `SELECT * FROM new_spots WHERE (NOW()-created_at)>45mins`  this isnt the correct syntax but what would be?

Comment: try this: WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 45 MINUTE)

Comment: Or perhaps just compute the correct value of the expired time in your host language (PHP or whatever you're using).  Then say WHERE created_at <= :expired_time;